# Why won't Eclipse open projects?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I'm running Helios SR2 and trying to open some old Eclipse based projects I pulled from the repository.  Unfortunately, it doesn't recognize the .project files.  I'm stuck using Eclipse as just a fancy text editor and compiling from the command line, which is most annoying.  :-)  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Or, better yet, any way to automate migrating Eclipse projects into Netbeans (all our new stuff is in Netbeans and it would nice to standardize on one platform)?

Comment: Are you sure the `.project` files were pulled with the rest of the project?

Comment: Yep, I can look at them in the repository and they match with what I have.  Eclipse seems to be ignoring them for some reason.

Comment: Do the projects appear in the Project Explorer view?

Comment: Maybe there's something missing from my Eclipse install?  The "Open Project" item in the "Project" menu is always grayed out too.

Comment: Nope, Project Explorer is completely empty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try (re)importing the projects. *File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace*.

Comment: "Cannot import into a workspace with no open projects. Please create a project before importing".  Do I have to create a project to be able to import my project?  Or is this just importing all the source files into a new project?

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce that. I'm able to make it work by importing "Existing Projects into Workspace."

Comment: In addition to this, I unchecked the "copy projects into workspace" checkbox.